# display live graph dynamic fetching from database in jsp

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, web

I need to display a live plotting column graph that should change on its own while accessing the database for every interval ,using java servlets and jsp in netbeans.I am not understanding how to integrate fetching of database values for a specific interval everytime and displaying that in a column graph
For fetching database into jsonarray

```
Connection con = null;
try {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:port/databasename","root","password");

    ResultSet rs = null;
    List Healthdetails = new LinkedList();
    JSONObject responseObj = new JSONObject();

    String query = "select * from data";
      PreparedStatement pstm= con.prepareStatement(query);

       rs = pstm.executeQuery();
       JSONObject hObj = null;

    while (rs.next()) {
                          //String name = rs.getString("name");
        int pulid = rs.getInt("pulse");
        hObj = new JSONObject();
        //empObj.put("name", name);
        hObj.put("pulseid", pulid);
        Healthdetails.add(hObj);
    }
    responseObj.put("Healthdetails", Healthdetails);
out.print(responseObj.toString());
}
catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if (con!= null) {
        try {
        con.close();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The json array is displaying perfectly,but i have no idea how to integrate this to display a live graph

For displaying graph ,but i have no proper idea if this is correct,on how to integrate the fetched jsonarray

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {
    var dataPoints = [];
    var chart;
        var xval=0;
        var yval=0;
        $.getJSON("http://localhost:8080/healthcare/new.jsp", function(data) {  
        $.each(data, function(key,value){
            dataPoints.push({x:xval , y: value[0]});
        });
        chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer",{
            title:{
                text:"Live Chart with dataPoints from External JSON"
            },
            data: [{
                type: "line",
                dataPoints : dataPoints,
            }]
        });
        chart.render();
        updateChart();
    //});
    });
    function updateChart() {
    $.getJSON("http://localhost:8080/healthcare/new.jsp", function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                        yVal=value['pulse'];
            dataPoints.push({
            x:xVal,     y: yVal});
                        xVal++;
        if (dataPoints.length >  10 )
        {
            dataPoints.shift();             
        }


        });
        chart.render();
        setTimeout(function(){updateChart()}, 2000);
    });
    }
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 300px; width: 100%;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions,have edited my question now..:)

Comment: Please help me with this question!!